# Is it ok to delete the Amazon .apk files?

Tags: apk, amazon-appstore

I have backed up all of my .apk files to my laptop. Can I delete the .apks in the Amazon venezia cache folder without detriment and be able to put them back on the sd card and reinstall from there at a later date, if I want to?

Comment: They're huge because games require a lot of resources.

Answer (score 4):

You can redownload them any time you want or just install them using a file manager, no need to put them back there.

If you backup them to your PC it's a good idea to use something like [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330359) to keep track of the various apks.

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb but, how can I tell which apps they are, since there's nothing in the file name to indicate this?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. I edited the answer with a link.

Answer (score 2):

Once the apps have been installed the APKs in the cache folder are completely worthless.  Even more so if you've backed them up.